# Java приложения - запуск на разных версиях

Tags: java, компиляция, jar

Заметил, что скомпилированный в jar проект java запускается на одном компе, но не запускается на другом. Я сразу понял, что дело в разных версиях Java, стоящих на этих компьютерах. Возник такой вопрос: а можно ли как-то скомпилировать проект так, чтобы он на разных версиях запускался? Ведь если подумать, то это неудобно: например, программист сделал приложение, выложил его в сеть, а пользователь должен сначала возиться с закачкой новой версии java, а потом только запускать приложение.

Comment: [Заметка](https://blog.codefx.org/tools/multi-release-jars-multiple-java-versions/) на тему.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, программист может при компиляции указать целевую платформу с помощью ключа [-target](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#BHCJDCID). Если в вашей программе используются только возможности Java 8 или более ранних версий, то собираете под Java 8 и можете быть уверены, что программа будет работать как на этой версии, так и на всех последующих, то есть у подавляющего большинства пользователей.

Во-вторых, начиная с Java 9 появилась возможность собирать [Multi-Release JAR Files](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/238). Если у пользователя Java 9 или более поздняя JRE, то из jar-файла запустятся class-файлы именно нужной версии.